# Explain the value returned in python dict method

Tags: python

Can someone explain to me what the following python code line returns? Im new to python

```
V[i].meesageout=\
dict([(x, array([1,1]))\
for x in V[i].neighbors])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line doesn't *return* anything.  It assigns a new dictionary to `V[i].mesageout`.  The dictionary has keys taken from `V[i].neighbors` and all the values are `array([1, 1])`  (presumably `numpy` arrays?)

---

Also, if you're new to python, please be aware that the line if formatted horribly.  This works:

```
V[i].messageout = dict((x, array([1, 1])) for x in V[i].neighbors)
```

or if you need to wrap, just wrap.  Don't use a \ because python will automatically continue lines while there is an unclosed parenthesis, bracket or brace.:

```
V[i].messageout = dict((x, array([1, 1]))
                       for x in V[i].neighbors)
```

Finally, on python2.7, you could use a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
V[i].messageout = {x: array([1, 1]) for x in V[i].neighbors}
```

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Without knowing I initialized V[i].mesageout as V[i].mesageout=[]. From what I know this is not  a dictionary but a list in python. But the dictionary returned from the dict() got assigned to it nicely and the program worked. How come? Are those two types compatible?

Comment: You just overwrite the former value. The list is gone now.

Comment: @user77005 -- Python objects are strongly and dynamically typed.  In other words, everything _has_ a type, but python doesn't care what the type is until it tries to use it.  In this case, the type of `V[i].messageout` _was_ list, but now it's _dict_.  So long as you use it as a _dict_ (until you change it again), the program will work.  Note that it is generally a good idea to make something 1 type and stick with it throughout the duration of the program -- It'll make your debugging life much easier :-).